# Vue Firebase : currentUser is null

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, vue.js

I'm new in Vue and Firebase. I'm using Firebase query to retrieve some data from Firebase database based on the current user email.

**This is working**

```
source:firebase.database().ref('service').orderByChild('userEmail').equalTo('shakil@gmail.com')
```

So in this case I'm using **firebase.auth().currentUser.email** for using current user email

**But this is not working**

```
source:firebase.database().ref('service').orderByChild('userEmail').equalTo(firebase.auth().currentUser.email)
```

It shows a error like this-> **firebase___default.a.auth(...).currentUser is null**

**And here is how Im using it into vuefire**

```
firebase: {
      services: {
        source: firebase.database().ref('service').orderByChild('userEmail').equalTo('marin@gmail.com'),
        readyCallback () {
          this.services.forEach(service => {
            firebase.storage()
              .ref(`service_images/${service.fileName}`)
              .getDownloadURL()
              .then(img => {
                this.$set(this.serviceImages, service['.key'], img)
              })
          })
        }
    }
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

During firebase initialization  `firebase.auth().currentUser` is null.
You should use

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
    // User is signed in.
  } else {
    // No user is signed in.
  }
});
```

as [firebase recommendation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users).

Comment: I need to retrieve current authenticate user's email. how can I get it by firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user){}

Comment: You can get `user.email` inside `firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user){}`

Comment: well when I console.log(user.email)  it shows the value.  but I cant show it into the template.   can you please tell me how can I show the current user email on the website

Comment: It's difficult to answer your question without knowing details about your project. How do you use `firebase.database().ref('service').orderByChild('userEmail').equalTo(firebase.auth().currentUser.email)` in your component?

Comment: I use Vuefire to display data ....here is the code 

firebase: {
      services: {
        source: firebase.database().ref('service').orderByChild('userEmail').equalTo('marin@gmail.com'),
        readyCallback () {
          this.services.forEach(service => {
            firebase.storage()
              .ref(`service_images/${service.fileName}`)
              .getDownloadURL()
              .then(img => {
                this.$set(this.serviceImages, service['.key'], img)
              })
          })
        }
    }
  },

Comment: Are you using `vuex`?

Comment: or you can check my full page code here on this link
https://docs.google.com/document/d/13znKb_jvdWb5KTpgTae6iTlB1NeSUjzM5k6M81E9mj4/edit?usp=sharing